# Vector as map value, insert new key and push back immediately c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

Does this work?

```
map<string, vector<int>> mymap;
mymap["bob"].push_back(1);
mymap["joe"].push_back(3);
mymap["joe"].push_back(12);
```

Or do I have to do this?

```
map<string, vector<int>> mymap;
if (mymap.find("bob") == mymap.end()) {
    vector<int> vec;
    mymap["bob"] = vec;
    mymap["bob"].push_back(1);
}
else {
    mymap["bob"].push_back(1);
}
...
```

Basically the question is whether or not mymap["bob"] creates the vector as its mapped value, or if I have to create a vector myself and add it into the map for new keys.

Comment: 1st version should work. Why don't you simply try out?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at: *"Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, **performing an insertion if such key does not already exist**. "*

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It is not because it seems to works that it is ok. There are a lot of UB which seems to works with simple try.

Comment: @Jarod42 Along with reading the reference documentation, it's clear it must work.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if people read documentation 95% of questions here would disappear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: your code is fine.

> #### std::map::operator[]
>
> ```
> mapped_type& operator[] (const key_type& k);
> ```
>
> If `k` matches the key of an element in the container, the function
>   returns a reference to its mapped value.
>
> **If `k` does not match the key of any element in the container, the function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference
>   to its mapped value.** Notice that this always increases the container
>   size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the
>   element is constructed using its default constructor).
>
> A similar member function, `map::at`, has the same behavior when an
>   element with the key exists, but throws an exception when it does not.

*source: [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/)*

Considering your second line, for example:

```
mymap["bob"].push_back(1);
```

`mymap` doesn't have a key `"bob"`, so it creates one and returns a reference to a *default-constructed* (i.e. empty) `vector<int>` associated with that key.

You then `push_back(1)` to that vector.  You could access `mymap["bob"]` again, and you'll get a reference to that vector, containing the single element `1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
map<string, vector<int>> mymap;
mymap["bob"].push_back(1);
```

should work. `map::operator[]` inserts an item for the given key if one doesn't already exist.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.